# SLES 11.1 install dvd accidentally added to yast

Tags: sles, sles11

I was attempting to install the SLES 11.1 SDK via yast and the dvdrom. I left the SLES SP1 install dvd in the drive accidentally and fired up yast. I also inadvertently added the actual OS install to yast. When I swap DVDs (and put in the SDK dvd) it squawks about not being able to find the SLES files. When I try to run the Software Manager and remove SLES from the list, it literally attempts to start removing all pieces/parts of SLES.

Is there any way to tell yast to just clear the queue of software to install? Multiple reboots and unmounts/remounts do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the sources in YAST -> Software -> Software Repositories ?

Comment: +1, removing the bad repo (the DVD) will indeed reset the to-install list.

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thanks guys/gals!

Comment: I did this on 11.3 and I ended up with nothing in my list of repositories!